# Driving GPIO outputs with FPGA: How to guarantee outputs of pins are set at same time

Tags: fpga, gpio, timing, propagation

I was recently asked a question by an interview. We were discussing a hypothetical device that needed to drive 8 GPIO outputs of the FPGA. I was asked how to reduce the influence of propagation delay of these 8 outputs.

That is, if I wanted to change the 8 outputs from 0 to 1, how to make the transitions of all these pins happen at the same time.

I understand that there is propagation delay as a signal traverses through a wire. If I have 8 registers, and the outputs of these registers lead to the 8 GPIO, there is no guarantee that these 8 outputs to the registers travel the same distance to get to the output of the FPGA, or observe the same capacitance and resistance.

Is there anything we can do to minimize the effect of this propagation delay?

I tried searching online, but was only finding discussions about propagation delay between registers.

Comment: Is the answer supposed to be a mundane answer? Because thinking that way, normally, you would try and clock it. Or use gray code if possible. Or use READ/select lines. It kinda depends on what you are allowed to do with this hypothetical device. Just all the normal stuff you see being used.

Comment: Maybe by registering all the 8 outputs.

Comment: First thing you should define what is the worst case *acceptable* timing. Then play from there

Comment: There is no such thing as absolute simultaneity in the real world.  You should reword your question along the lines of "How to guarantee that the outputs of pins all arrive within 500 ps of each other".

Answer (score 4):

*"...a hypothetical device that needed to drive 8 GPIO outputs of the FPGA. I was asked how to reduce the influence of propagation delay of these 8 outputs."*

Use the I/O pin DFFs. All modern FPGAs and some CPLDs provide at least three on each pin:

- Input DFF
- Output DFF
- Output tri-state control DFF

Most provide two more DFFs for Double Data Rate (DDR) pin changes on both clock edges, not just on one edge.

These I/O pin DFFs are located a fixed distance from the I/O pin. They therefore have a fixed path timing relationship with it, excluding tiny variations for temperature, operating voltage and part variance.

The DFF-to-I/O pin propagation timings will be specified in the part datasheets etc. It's typically well under 1 ns.

A physical constraint must be added to your synthesis project for each pin to ensure its use. Obviously, the design must have a DFF on the input or output, not combinatorial logic, otherwise they cannot be used and the constraint will be ignored.

Every FPGA/CPLD design I've done uses pin DFFs for all pins with multi-clock timing (i.e. 1..n clocks). It cannot be done with pins having sub-clock timing but they're in the minority for all the FPGA designs out there. It also can't be done for pins on combinatorial paths.

Wherever possible, have all of the logic circuit 'sandwiched' between I/O pin DFFs running from a single common clock.

This produces a completely stable design across changes and recompilations and across temperature and supply voltage tolerance. Such a design needs no I/O timing constraints beyond the pin DFF constraints.

A minor thing: FPGAs/CPLDs don't have General-Purpose I/O (GPIO) pins - MCUs do. On FPGAs, they're always I/O pins in the documentation.

Comment: This certainly helps, but it doesn't solve the problem completely because the clock transition still arrives at the different flip-flops with some skew.  Dedicated clock routing trees help but the pin location will still be the dominant effect, larger than temperature and supply voltage gradients.

Comment: @BenVoigt, actually the timing-driven placement software removes the effect of clock skew for the I/O pin DFFs. Look through how the placement software works - it's based on clock path and signal path timing. (I won't reiterate it all here or post links, we'll get a lengthy comment discussion on something already documented. Can chat though.) You won't see the effects of clock skew between I/O pin DFFs changing on the same clock, just the other variances. Wide data buses need this. The placement tool needs to account for clock path timing to make a synchronous circuit across a whole device.

Comment: @BenVoigt On newer FPGA platforms such as Spartan-7, there are dedicated clock nets within each I/O bank which are presumably tuned to minimize this skew as much as possible (one cited use is for source-synchronous capture). Does the same concern apply there, or only when the clock is coming from a global or regional clock tree (and if so, would something like an ODELAY resolve this concern)?

Comment: You would implement GPIO using IOB resources.

Answer (score 1):

Register the outputs and constrain the timing appropriately.
The key to FPGA IO timing is the constraints file.

Sometimes you can use an attribute to force the placer to use a register built into the pin driver block which is about as good as it gets (Often it will do this automatically, but you can sometimes also control this behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Register all the signals on the same clock, and constrain them properly in the XDC file using your required max and min output delay. That’s the general answer that is independent of architecture, be it ASIC or FPGA. You do this *first* to capture system design intent. I would surmise that the interviewer is probing to see if you know about this.

Within the FPGA flow you have an additional tool at your disposal: set a property in your HDL source to direct the tool flow to use IOB flops, that have lower (and better-controlled) output delay than routing from an internal flop.

Example:

```
(* IOB = "true" *) reg sig1;
```

The tool will notice this and route a low-skew clock to the IOB flop as well as your logic signal.

Finally, using IOB flops implies that you’re willing to constrain the pin placement in a way that lets the flops share a low-skew clock.

So that’s three things you need to do to achieve the best possible timing:

- constrain the timing
- constrain the pin placement for clock routing
- Set the IOB attribute on your source